# See CSS of :after activated on hover in dev tools

Tags: google-developer-tools

In Google developer tools A website applies an :after only on hover.

Therefore, when I hover on an element I can't move my mouse to the :after in dev tools to see the css.

Is there a way to pause on hover in dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

You can pause various states of an element by going to "elements tab" and selecting the element in question in the DOM tree shown.

Click ":hov" and select the state you want the element to be in.

[image: Chrome developer tool hover]

Comment: I can't select the element in question because it is an :after that only appears on hover of another element.